# Editing the output of uniq -c (Bash)

Tags: bash

I have a list of words that I sorted using `sort -f`. Now, I want to use `uniq -c` in order to obtain a list without repeated words but with a counter on the left side. I also want the column with the numbers to be separated by a tab from the column with the words.

This is my list:

```
Monday       day
Tuesday      day
Easter       holiday
Monday       day
christmas    holiday
Tuesday      day
Friday       day
Thursday     day
thanksgiving holiday
```

And this is my desired output:

```
1    christmas    holiday
1    Easter       holiday
1    Friday       day
2    Monday       day
1    thanksgiving holiday
1    Thursday     day
2    Tuesday      day
```

I tried using the following command, though I get a tab before the numbers instead of between the numbers and the words.

```
sort -f | uniq -c | sed $'s/\t */\t/g'
```

What do I have to modify in order to get the output that I want?

Comment: @lurker `$'...'` makes the shell process escape sequences in the string so that `\t` is translates to TAB.

Comment: @Barmar ah ok, thanks. It seems to translate `\t` fine for me, without the `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the number in a capture group and copy it to the replacement so you can put the tab after it.

```
sort -f days.txt | uniq -c | sed $'s/^ *\([0-9]*\) */\\1\t/'
```

`uniq -c` doesn't put tab before the count, it just puts spaces.